# Broken link of SO/SE-Blog

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, broken-link

I looked around and got [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/welcome-valued-associate-nick-craver/). But clicking on [" the Stack Overflow reputation leagues for 2010"](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2010-01-01) (the link under the second image or itself) returns an [error](https://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2010-01-01).

I tried to find other (old) blog entries with same problem, but did not succeed in some time. So I just follow the advice to give a note here.

My questions:

1. Is there a status-by-design, that links like this disappears some time?
2. Is there a collecting-question for that? The automatic advice is to post it here.(First pages of search for "blog link broken" were sth. else)
3. Or is it just a "victim" of a redesign?

Comment: I get an error too, when I try visiting http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2010-01-01.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a timeout on this large API call over the weekend (we now fetch all the league data for an interval in a single call, rather than as a nightly batch process), I believe the issue has been resolved but we'll keep an eye on it just in case.